# Show that $\phi$ is an isometry

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, lp-spaces, isometry

The following Lemma can be obtained in '[Geometric Nonlinear Functional Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821808354)' by Benyamini and Lindenstrauss, page $2.$

> **Lemma:** Every metric space $X$ is isometric to a subset of
> $\ell_{\infty}(\Gamma)$ for some set $\Gamma.$

Proof: Fix any $x_0 \in X,$ and take $\Gamma$ to be the set $X$ itself.
The embedding $\phi:X \rightarrow \ell_{\infty}(\Gamma)$ is defined by
$$\phi(x)(y) = d(x,y) - d(x_0,y).$$

> Question: How to show that $\phi$ is an isometry between $X$ and $\ell_{\infty}(\Gamma)?$

We want to show that $ d(\phi(x), \phi(z)) = d(x,z)$ for every $x,z \in X.$

Observe that for each $x \in X,$
$$\sup_{y \in X}|\phi(x)(y)| = \sup_{y \in X}|d(x,y)-d(x_0,y)| \leq \sup_{y \in X}|d(x,x_0)| = |d(x,x_0)|.$$
I do not know how to continue.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: $\|x\|$ makes no sense for $x\in X$. A metric space is not necessarily a normed space. You would need to show that distances are preserved, i.e., $\|\phi(x)-\phi(y)\|_{\ell^\infty} = d(x,y) ``='' \|x - y\|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that:
$$\sup_{y\in X}| d(x,y) - d(x_0,y) - d(z,y)+d(x_0,y)|=\sup_{y\in X}|d(x,y)-d(z,y)|≥|d(x,z)-d(z,z)|=d(x,z)$$
and via the lower triangle inequality you have $|d(x,y)-d(z,y)|≤d(x,z)$ for any $y$. So
$$d(\phi(x),\phi(z))=\|\phi(x)-\phi(z)\|_\infty = d(x,z)$$

Comment: The inequality $|d(x,y)-d(z,y)|≤d(x,z)$ _is_ the lower triangle inequality for $d$. I don't see what you mean with it following from the definition of the supremum.